# Why is State Undefined? [Hooks/Redux]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to use Redux via hooks but the state keeps coming back with an empty array rather than the data from the fetch request.

Actions

```
export const loading = payload => {
    return {
        type: types.LOADING,
        payload
    }
}

export const getBudget = payload => {
    return {
        type: types.BUDGET_DATA,
        payload
    }
}

export const budgetData = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loading(true))
        const url = `${URL_BUDGET}`
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => dispatch(getBudget(response.data)))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        dispatch(loading(false))
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
import * as types from '../types'

const initialState = {
    budget: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.types) {
        case types.BUDGET_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                budget: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Component

```
const Home = () => {
    useDispatch(budgetData(), categoryData())
    const state = useSelector(state => state.data)
    const budgets = useSelector(state => state.data.budget)
    const categories = useSelector(state => state.data.category)

    //console.log(this.props.dataReducer)
    return (
        <div>
            content
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

I can't seem to understand why the fetch request isn't fulfilled.

My API has the following format of data...

```
{"meta":{},"data":{"example":[{"timestamp":28378545,"value":5}],...}}
```

Is there an issue with dispatching?! Adding loading hasn't helped either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) returns a `dispatch` function that subsequently needs to be called. If you want to do this just one time when the component is first rendered, you can pair it with a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) that has no dependencies:

```js
const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const budgets = useSelector(state => state.data.budget)
    const categories = useSelector(state => state.data.category)

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(budgetData())
      dispatch(categoryData())
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            content
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```